# Differences between definitions of regular conditional distributions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and let $X:(\Omega, \mathcal{A}) \rightarrow (\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{F})$ and $Y:(\Omega, \mathcal{A}) \rightarrow (\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{G})$ be random variables.

Now I am interested in the differences between the differences between the following two objects:

i.) Regular conditional distribution of X under Y:

A Markov kernel from $(\Omega, \sigma(Y))$ into $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{F})$ is called regular conditional distribution of X under Y, $K:= \mathbb{P}_{X\mid Y}$ iff:
$$K(\cdot, A)=\mathbb{P}(X\in A\mid \sigma(Y)), \quad \text{for all } A\in \mathcal{F} $$

ii.) Regular conditional distribution of X under Y=y:

A Markov kernel from $(\mathcal{Y}, \mathcal{G})$ into $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{F})$ is called a factorized regular conditional distribution of X under Y=y, $K(y, \cdot) = \mathbb{P}_{X\mid Y=y}$, iff:
$$K(y, A) = \mathbb{P}(X\in A\mid Y=y), \quad\mathbb{P}\text{-almost surely, } \quad A\in \mathcal{F}$$

My questions are now the following:

1.) Are both $\mathbb{P}_{X\mid Y}$ and $\mathbb{P}_{X\mid Y=y}$ pushforward measures?

2.) why is (ii) only defined up to $\mathbb{P}$-almost surely ( (and (i) not) ?

3.) So $\mathbb{P}_{X\mid Y}$ should accept to inputs, right? One $A\in\mathcal{F}$ and the other a number. The question is though from which set? Does it get an $\omega \in \Omega$ or a $y\in\mathcal{Y}$ which the notation suggests? Which one does it use as input and why?

4.) And how are the two definitions generally related? The notation suggests that $\mathbb{P}_{X\mid Y}$ should accept two arguments, $y\in \mathcal{Y}$ and $A\in\mathcal{F}$, while $\mathbb{P}_{X\mid Y=y}$ should only accept an $A\in\mathcal{F}$ (assuming here that the answer to Question 1.) was yes that indeed both are pushforward measures). So the notation also seems to suggest that $\mathbb{P}_{X\mid Y=y}$ is somehow a paremetric version of $\mathbb{P}_{X\mid Y}$ where one variable was just simply fixed. Is that indeed the case?

Comment: Please rewrite in latex style everything that wasn't written in it yet. also, what do you mean by certain probabilities being pushforward measures?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your comment. So distributions of random variables are pushforward measures, for instance $\mathbb{P}_X(A) = \mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega)\in A\})$, i.e., the distribution of $X$ is defined as a pushforward measure w.r.t. the reference measure $\mathbb{P}$. But I am not sure if this is also true in the case of these (regular) conditional distributions, i.e., if they are also pushforward measures. If they are not I think the notation of them is at least misleading

Comment: Can you point to the source of these definitions, especially, the factorized regular conditional distribution? It looks like disintegration.

Comment: I have mostly been looking at a book that is not available in english. What would you need to know to maybe answer my questions? Btw I think the answer to i) is that it is only defined almost surely as well but it was forgotten in the book that I am reading